# php call function using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show qrcode on my page, but for performance reasons, I don't want my page loads the qrcode on page load. I put qrcode on bootstrap5 modal box and I want load qrcode when user clicks on the modal botton.
This is my code:

```
function qrcode($page_id) {
    $url = DOMAIN.DS.$page_id;
    $size = '256x256';
    $color = '000000'; //RGB code without #
    $bgcolor = 'ffffff'; //RGB code without #
    $margin = '1px';
    $width = '36px';
    $height = '36px';
    
    if (is_file(FILE.'image'.DS.'icon'.DS.'system'.DS.'qrcode.jpg')) {
        $qrthumb = DOMAIN.DS.'file'.DS.'image'.DS.'icon'.DS.'system'.DS.'qrcode.jpg';
    } else {
        $qrthumb = $qrsrc;
    }
    
    $qrcode = '<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#qrcode'.$page_id.'">
                    <img width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$qrthumb.'" alt="Scan QR-Code" title="Scan QR-Code" />
                </a>
                <div class="modal" id="qrcode'.$page_id.'">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body tcenter">
                                <div id="showqrcode"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#showqrcode").on("onload", function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "",
                                success:function(data){
                                    $("#showqrcode").html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                ';

    return $qrcode;
}

function getqrcode($url,$size,$color,$bgcolor,$margin) {
    $qrsrc = 'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data='.$url.'&amp;size='.$size.'&amp;color='.$color.'&amp;bgcolor='.$bgcolor.'&amp;margin='.$margin;
    $qrimage = '<img width="256px" height="256px" src="'.$qrsrc.'" alt="Scan QR-Code" title="Scan QR-Code" />';
    return $qrimage;
}
```

I want when modal is loading and showing , function getqrcode runs and return the <img...

Thank you

Comment: So what isn't working and what is your question?

Comment: I don't know where and how to call getqrcode function